# Is there a way to see when a Slack user is typically online?

Tags: slack

I'm a freelance programmer and one of my clients has a Slack workspace that I use to communicate with coworkers. To do my work I often need to ask questions of one or more of my coworkers, but often the person I need to talk to is not online, and I have no sense of when they are likely to be online.

Is there some built-in Slack feature or Slack add-on that would allow me to get a sense of when a person is typically online? Like showing when they've been online over the past week?

Comment: Most services have a list of features. Have you reviewed if Slack developers / sales people have posted something like that? Asking for add-ons is off-topic; try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some built-in Slack feature or Slack add-on that would allow me to get a sense of when a person is typically online? Like showing when they've been online over the past week?

I haven't seen any such built-in Slack feature available to any users. However, a workspace admin can view when a user connected to their account. From [slack.com/help](https://slack.com/help/articles/360002084807-View-Access-Logs-for-your-workspace#:%7E:text=Understand%20Access%20Log%20entries,their%20computer%20or%20mobile%20device):

> **Understand Access Log entries**
>
> When members are connected to and actively using Slack, workspace Access Logs are updated every hour. New entries are generated when members do any of the following:
>
> - Sign in to their account
> - Open the Slack app on their computer or mobile device
> - Sign in with a unique IP address and a desktop or mobile device
> - Change their [availability](https://slack.com/help/articles/201864558-Set-your-Slack-status-and-availability) from away to active